# Swift 3 Custom Cell Brings Error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I've tried multiple things to try and get a simple title and message table cell in Swift 3. This is the furthest and closest I've gotten for it to work. I am getting a `Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT` error on the first line of my App Delegate file and `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` in my console output.

Cell Class. The outlets are connected to the prototype cell in my storyboard file.

```
import UIKit
class MyTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
}
```

Code to load table

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell

    if cell == nil {
        let cell:MyTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MyTableCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = posts[indexPath.row].message
        return cell
    } else {
        cell.label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
        cell.label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message
    }



    return cell
}
```

**Note:** I found the code above to load the table online. This was my more simple code below that wasn't working properly.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:MyTableCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! MyTableCell

    cell.label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    cell.label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].message

    return cell
}
```

Comment: `1).` Add an exception breakpoint so that your code stops on the line with the error. `2).` Add the relevant lines from your exception log (i.e. the specific error that caused the app to stop) to the question. `3).` You probably want the newer version of `dequeueReusableCell`: `let cell: MyTableCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableCell` which is guaranteed to be non-nil. `4).` Check you have set the correct cell identifier in the Storyboard and that the class of your custom cell is correct.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @RoboticCat that is not the newest version, as quick fix updates it to `        let cell: MyTableCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell` which is what I had in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `nil` is returned when calling `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, you must instantiate the cell using the designated `UITableViewCell` initializer. The code you provided turns around and calls `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` again which will once again return nil.

To instantiate a new cell, use the following:

`let cell = MyTableCell( style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "MyTableCell" )`

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: This gives me a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` error on my next line.

Comment: You'll have to use a style of `value1`, `value2`, or `subtitle` if you wish to use the `detailTextLabel`.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep yet. Sorry!

Comment: Would this cause problems with mbedding the view in a navigation controller? Seems to be not working.